# contactPickerDidCancel and contactPicker Functions are never called

Tags: ios, swift

Hello I'm new to iOS design and Swift and I'm trying to implement a simple Contact picker that allows the user to simply select a contact. I have a button in a view controller and the view controller conforms to the CNContactPickerDelegate, but when I run the app and use the picker, my contactPickerDidCancel function and my contactPicker function never get called no matter what I press inside the picker. As far as I understand, the picker should call the functions I wrote when I click not he cancel button or a contact inside the picker. Is this wrong? Any help or ideas would be great! Thanks!

UPDATE: Solved. It was a simple syntax error. In both functions, I didn't put an underscore before "picker".

```
@IBAction func addContactPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    let contactPickerViewController = CNContactPickerViewController()

    contactPickerViewController.delegate = self

    contactPickerViewController.predicateForEnablingContact = NSPredicate(format: "phoneNumbers.@count > 0", argumentArray: nil)

    contactPickerViewController.predicateForSelectionOfProperty =
        NSPredicate(format: "key == 'phoneNumbers'", argumentArray: nil)

    contactPickerViewController.displayedPropertyKeys = [CNContactEmailAddressesKey, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey]

    self.present(contactPickerViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}


func contactPickerDidCancel(picker: CNContactPickerViewController) {
    print("Cancelled picking a contact.")
}

func contactPicker(picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelectContact contact: CNContact) {
    print("Selected a contact.")
    if contact.isKeyAvailable(CNContactPhoneNumbersKey) {
        print(contact.phoneNumbers)
    }
    else {
        print("No phone numbers are available.")
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your class conforms to that delegate?

Answer (score 1):

You have to rewrite `CNContactPickerDelegate` methods with new signature :

```
func contactPicker(_ picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelect contact: CNContact) {
    //handle contact
}

func contactPickerDidCancel(_ picker: CNContactPickerViewController) {
    //handle cancel event
}
```

Underscore `_` will **Omitting Argument Labels** from methods in new `swift` syntax. So use new signature.

Answer (score 0):

move the contact picker outside of the function, your losing reference to it once your out of that scope. You can make it an optional and then initialize it once the button it clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Did you make your view controller conform to **CNContactPickerDelegate**??

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, CNContactPickerDelegate {

    }
```